# click() after changed class

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have this code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.notUsed').click(function(){
        $(this).attr('class', 'used');
    });
});

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.used').click(function(){
        alert("Are you sure you want to do this?");
    });
});


<div class="notUsed"></div>
```

And after I click on the div the first time everything works fine, the stlye changes and everything. But when i click on it the second time, the second event won't trigger. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It is never binding the event. Because there is no elements with that class when you try to bind it on document ready

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This syntax:

`$('.used').click(function(){`

binds all the current elements with the classname 'used'. Since the used class is added after the document is initially loaded, you need to bind it dynamically:

`$(document).click('.used',function(){`

If possible, you should use the parent of `.used` as a selector instead of the document.

Comment: Note: The `'.used'` will be [treated as `eventData`](http://api.jquery.com/click/#click-eventData-handler). jQuery's `.click()` doesn't have an overload for accepting selectors.

Comment: Ah, now i get your answer. But what is the difference/benefits from using tymeJV answer?

Comment: In tymeJV's answer, you rebind .used every time, which means if you have multiple buttons with the .used class, the function will be called multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

Event handlers are bound at runtime - so when your class changes the second handler still does not know about that element. You can either bind the second handler at the time of class change or use event delegation. Also, you only need 1 DOM ready event:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.notUsed').click(function(){
        $(this).addClass('used').removeClass('notUsed');
        $(this).off("click"); //unbind this handler

        $('.used').click(function(){
            alert("Are you sure you want to do this?");
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: it is not a good practice to use `attr()` for setting a class. Because it will remove all the element class. maybe it is better to use `removeClass()` and `addClass()`

Comment: @tymeJV if you have two or more .notUsed elements, this code is gonna be messy. Say you click div 1, then div 2, then div 1: the alert will pop up twice because you bind click on .used multiple times

Comment: @Izzey -- Ahh yeah...very true - wanted to do this without `.on` (not sure why, but who knows) - OP should go ahead and mark your answer.

Answer (score 0):

It never binds beceuse when you run `$('.used').click(function(){` there is no element `.used` this should work

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.notUsed').live('click', function(){
        $(this).attr('class', 'used');
    });

    $('.used').live('click', function(){
        alert("Are you sure you want to do this?");
    });
});


<div class="notUsed"></div>
```

Comment: Live is deprecated and even removed in the newest versions of jquery

Comment: I have to admit that I did not used jQuery for a while, prefer modern frameworks

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) for your events to work:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.not-used').on("click", function () {
        $(this).removeClass('not-used').addClass('used');
    });

    $(document).on('click', '.used', function () {
        alert("Are you sure you want to do this?");
    });
});
```

Comment: If you have multiple .not-used you are adding multiple event handlers, since you're binding it inside the not-used.click function

Comment: You are right. I misplaced the closing tags. Edited the answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have the element right there in the callback why not bind a new EventListener to it

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.not-used').on("click.first", function () {
    $(this)
      .removeClass('not-used')
      .addClass('used')
      .off('click.first')
      .on('click.second', function(){
        alert("Are you sure you want to do this?");
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use

```
<div class="element used"></div>
```

To handle click

```
$(".element").on("click",function(){
     this.classList.toggle("used");
     this.classList.toggle("notUsed");
});
```

Just handle event 1 time.

Hope it'll help you